# Matlab mesh step

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm developing a tool in Matlab where I use `meshgrid`

```
    x= -a:a/101:a;
    y= -a:a/101:a;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

to define the points where a field `E` is computed. Therefore I have `E(X,Y)` and in this way I would have that for a specific point in the mesh, it's associate a value for the field.  I have a function that compute E in all the points

```
E = compute_field(X,Y)
```

Then I do some operation to this field (sums and multiplications) inside another function which give me two results representing all the possible errors in the two directions.

```
[ERR_H,ERR_V] = ideal_computations(E,X,Y)
```

So far there are no problems.

In the next step of my tool I decide to impose the two points x,y to extract the value of this field in order to have `E(x,y)` scalar and not matrix like before

```
e = compute_field(x,y)
```

and I do exactly the same sums and multiplications that I did before.

```
[ERR_H,ERR_V] = real_computations(e,x,y)
```

For now the two functions `ideal_computations` and `real_computations` are exactly the same.
Then I check where `E(x,y)` is inside `E(X,Y)` computing the minimum value between the two and extract the coordinates and the problem is here.

```
[x1_est,x2_est] = compute_error(err_h,err_v,X,Y,ERR_H,ERR_V)
row = (size(ERR_H,1)+1)/2;
col = (size(ERR_V,2)+1)/2;

[~,m] = min(abs(ERR_H(row,:)-err_h));
[~,n] = min(abs(ERR_V(:,col)-err_v));

x1_est = X(n,m);
x2_est = Y(n,m);
```

Probably the couple `(X,Y)` doesn't have the step to match perfectly `(x,y)` and I get this

[image]

This probably happens when I compute the minimum and the result is not exactly zero, therefore there is this kind of mismatch.

For example I put the points `(0.0651,0.0651)`. This function go check the position of that point, or the one that is close to `0.0651`. Looking at the matrices, I see that the closest value is `0.065076334365630`, which is not exactly `0.0651`. To get min=0 I should have inside the matrices the value 0.0651 and in that case I will have the two points overlapped.
I don't want to increase the step because maybe could even work with this field but maybe not with another one, plus I will have a very large matrices that will need to much effort to be computed.
How can I solve this problem? Is there any other ways to do the same not using meshgrid but something that always works?

Comment: Without you showing any kind of code other than the `meshgrid` call it's hard to say, but two thoughts: `interp2` or make a function out of the call to `E`, and let that exactly calculate the value based on your desired `(x,y)`.

Comment: I've added something. I didn't want to enter too much in detail because there are many function that I don't care at this level. The problem is just with the mesh I think

Comment: How can I use interp2 in a 2D plot?

Comment: The documentation on [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) has a lot of examples on usage.